# How can i use swift enums in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have imported an `swift library` to my project which has enums, i am unable to use those enums in `objective c` project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift enums can now be exported to `Objective-C` using the `@objc` attribute — For example, the following Swift code:

```
@objc enum Bear: Int {
    case Black, Grizzly, Polar
}
```